# How do I create polygon based private blockchain like Ethereum using geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, polygon

I have been going through polygon blockchain. I understand that to reduce transaction cost and improve throughput, polygon employs zkrollups. However, I have not found any blogs or documents about creating a simple private testbed setup to simulate polygon. I earlier created ethereum private testnet with 5 nodes using geth and also ran smart contracts in the private network with clique consensus. Is there a way to create polygon like this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are nowadays quite many different Polygon networks... I guess you mean [Polygon zkEVM Beta](https://polygon.technology/polygon-zkevm).

Blockchains are getting a lot more complicated nowadays. Gone are the days when you could just fire up Geth and add nodes - except for some older blockchains.

Running your own "test" zkEVM is far from trivial. You'd need at least:

1. Run a sequencer. I don't know if there are any publicly available which are compatible.
2. Run a prover. Most likely there are none publicly available currently.
3. Configure everything

Depending on your needs, you may want to look into running an arbitrary blockchain on top of some existing (complicated) blockchain, such as Polygon Beta, as a new layer.